# Can't get references between <script> tags in html file with json schema using python beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-jsonschema

I need to access to json references in *local* html file with json schema. The references are located between first  tags in file.

```
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // Script section to load models into a JS Var
    var defs = {}
        defs["AccountIdentifier"] = {
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "activity" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Describes the account state, if it has been activated or not.",
      "enum" : [ "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "NOT_ACTIVATED" ]
    }
```

However, when I use beautifulsoup, it doesn't take above  tags and takes the parts which are between the second  tags.

My code is as below:

```
with io.open(localUrl, 'rt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    print('Reading file..')

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file.read(), 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
    ab = soup.body.findAll(text='defs["ResourceReference"]')
    print('Sample Reference', ab)
```

When I write soup to file, I get what I want - json references. However, it's lost when I print it to stdout.

Note: I also tried PyQt5 using this video...: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU&t=537s

Answer (score 0):

there is an ugly but working way how to solve it

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<script>
    // Script section to load models into a JS Var
    var defs = {}
        defs["AccountIdentifier"] = {
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "activity" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Describes the account state, if it has been activated or not.",
      "enum" : [ "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "NOT_ACTIVATED" ]
    }
    }
    }
</script>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find("script") # selector to find required script

script = result.text.replace('\n', '')
script = script.split(' = ')[-1]

print(json.loads(script.strip()))
```